# Header and Footer not showing from Page Design after publish

Tags: sxa

I have an SXA site, with a Page Design mapped to my pages with header and footer partial designs populated and enabled. It works fine in preview and edit mode. But after I publish to the web database, the header and footer don't show up.

I'm not sure what's going on. I checked the related content items in the web database, everything is there. All the partial designs, page designs, etc. The Page Designs are mapped to the proper page templates also.

Not sure what's going on. I tried a full republish of everything (sometimes smart publish is not so smart in my experience), but the header and footer will not show up on the published page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If renderings from partial designs are injected in edit and preview modes then I'm almost sure that there is a problem with publishing. Something must be missing in the web database.

Try to:

- instead of using "Template to Design Mapping" field try to assign page design manually and check if this works (each page has Page Design field):

  [image: List item]
- manually create a new page and partial design in the web database - simply repeat the steps you did in master but this time right away in the web database. If this will work you will have a confirmation that it is a problem with publishing.

Comment: thanks for this. This wasn't the problem, but it did lead me down the road towards the eventual solution. See my answer for the resolution I came to.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. I had broken links in my partial designs as well as my home page. Once I fixed the broken links, I republished and the header and footer displayed on the published page.